# Couchbase Full text search matching partial numbers

Tags: full-text-search, couchbase, sql++

Good day.

I am using couchDB to store data of some entity which includes "firstName", "lastName", "dob" and "idNumber".  (Various other dynamic data is also present, but not important now.)

I have created a full-text-search index to index specific types of documents and set up to search on the above mentioned fields only.  The search works perfectly for "firstName" and "lastName" with partial matches as well.

However, for the idNumber, the exact number must be given.  Partial searches on the idNumber does not work.  For example, if '7605054321089' is the idNumber and I search for '760505432', nothing is returned.  If I enter the idNumber completely, it is returned successfully.  I have fiddled with the properties under the FTS section, to no avail.

My date-of-birth field does not work at all.  I cannot search on that field, but I have parked that until I get the idNumber to work at least.

The JSon describing the filter as follows (sorry for the size):

```
{
  "type": "fulltext-index",
  "name": "entities_fts",
  "uuid": "5c5dc5e32083535f",
  "sourceType": "couchbase",
  "sourceName": "entities",
  "sourceUUID": "04bb2840ed12d26003797737e5a19908",
  "planParams": {
    "maxPartitionsPerPIndex": 32,
    "numReplicas": 0,
    "hierarchyRules": null,
    "nodePlanParams": null,
    "pindexWeights": null,
    "planFrozen": false
  },
  "params": {
    "mapping": {
      "byte_array_converter": "json",
      "default_analyzer": "standard",
      "default_datetime_parser": "dateTimeOptional",
      "default_field": "_all",
      "default_mapping": {
        "display_order": "1",
        "dynamic": true,
        "enabled": false
      },
      "default_type": "_default",
      "index_dynamic": true,
      "store_dynamic": false,
      "type_field": "header.type",
      "types": {
        "person": {
          "display_order": "0",
          "dynamic": false,
          "enabled": true,
          "properties": {
            "basic": {
              "display_order": "1",
              "dynamic": false,
              "enabled": true,
              "properties": {
                "dob": {
                  "dynamic": false,
                  "enabled": true,
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "analyzer": "",
                      "display_order": "0",
                      "include_in_all": true,
                      "include_term_vectors": true,
                      "index": true,
                      "name": "",
                      "store": false,
                      "type": "datetime"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "firstNames": {
                  "dynamic": false,
                  "enabled": true,
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "analyzer": "",
                      "display_order": "2",
                      "include_in_all": true,
                      "include_term_vectors": true,
                      "index": true,
                      "name": "",
                      "store": false,
                      "type": "text"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "lastNames": {
                  "dynamic": false,
                  "enabled": true,
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "analyzer": "",
                      "display_order": "1",
                      "include_in_all": true,
                      "include_term_vectors": false,
                      "index": true,
                      "name": "",
                      "store": false,
                      "type": "text"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "extended": {
              "display_order": "0",
              "dynamic": false,
              "enabled": true,
              "properties": {
                "idNumber": {
                  "dynamic": false,
                  "enabled": true,
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "analyzer": "keyword",
                      "display_order": "0",
                      "include_in_all": true,
                      "include_term_vectors": false,
                      "index": true,
                      "name": "",
                      "store": false,
                      "type": "text"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "store": {
      "kvStoreName": "forestdb"
    }
  },
  "sourceParams": {
    "clusterManagerBackoffFactor": 0,
    "clusterManagerSleepInitMS": 0,
    "clusterManagerSleepMaxMS": 2000,
    "dataManagerBackoffFactor": 0,
    "dataManagerSleepInitMS": 0,
    "dataManagerSleepMaxMS": 2000,
    "feedBufferAckThreshold": 0,
    "feedBufferSizeBytes": 0
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the idNumber search in couchbase FTS, it might be because you're attempting an exact match search?  You might want to try a prefix search...

```
    {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 10,
        "query": {
            "field": "name",
            "prefix": "bobble"
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/blevesearch/bleve/blob/master/test/tests/basic/searches.json#L91

Comment: You are spot-on.  I changed to a ConjunctionQuery where each conjuct is a PrefixQuery with a tokenized search term.  Now searches such as "Pet Smi" returns "Peter Smith".  Works great, thank you.